# I can't organize my messages by recent chat in Django

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to fix my messages in order to show the messages by most recent. I can't figure out where did I go wrong in the code.

The output in my inbox shows the list of newly created conversations with a new user on the very top followed by the previous messages. Whenever I try to message the other person in my inbox, it does not go up as the most recent in the list. I am hoping to put the most recent on the top of the list.

I am thinking that I can use sent_at to know the last active conversation in an active chat but I don't know where to start.

Here are my codes:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

AUTH_USER_MODEL = getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', 'auth.User')

class Message(models.Model):
    """
    A private direct message.
    """
    content = models.TextField('Content')
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='direct_messages', blank=True, null=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='sent_dm', verbose_name='Sender'
    )
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='received_dm', verbose_name='Recipient'
    )
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField('sent at', auto_now_add=True)
    read_at = models.DateTimeField('read at', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-sent_at']

    @property
    def unread(self):
        """
        Returns whether the message was read or not.
        """
        if self.read_at is not None:
            return True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Check message sender and recipient and raise error if the are saved.
        Save message when the condition passes.
        """
        if self.sender == self.recipient:
            raise ValidationError("You cant't send messages to yourself!")

        if not self.id:
            self.sent_at = timezone.now()
        super(Message, self).save(**kwargs)

class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    """
    A private char room

    Attributes:
        created_at (datetime): datetime value when chatroom is created.
        recipient (user): user whom the chatroom sends first message.
        sender (user): user who created the chatroom
    """
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='chatroom_sender', verbose_name='Sender'
    )
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='chatroom_recipient'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('sent at', auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ('sender', 'recipient')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic import CreateView, RedirectView

from .models import Message, ChatRoom
from .forms import MessageForm
from .services import MessagingService
from users.models import User

class MessageDetailView(CreateView):
    """
    Show a messages, and could send messages.
    """
    model = ChatRoom
    form_class = MessageForm
    template_name = 'direct_messages/direct_messages.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns conversations based on different conditions.
        1. Fetch message based on chatroom (sender, recipient)
        2. Fetch current conversation of the current user and assign it
        to conversations context value
        3. If current loggedIn user is sender, active_recipient will be
        message recipient otherwise, message sender.
        4. Fetch active conversation for message / chat tab.
        :param kwargs: Description
        :return: Description
        """
        chat_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')

        chatroom = ChatRoom.objects.get(pk=chat_id)

        message = Message.objects.filter(
            sender=chatroom.sender,
            recipient=chatroom.recipient
        ).first()
        if not message:
            message = Message.objects.filter(
                sender=chatroom.sender,
                recipient=chatroom.recipient
            ).first()

        # MessagingService().mark_as_read(message)
        user = self.request.user

        kwargs['active_conversation'] = message
        current_conversations = MessagingService().get_conversations(user=self.request.user)
        kwargs['conversations'] = current_conversations



        if user == message.sender:
            active_recipient = message.recipient
            # kwargs['recipient'] = User.objects.get(username=message.recipient)
        else:
            active_recipient = message.sender
            # kwargs['sender'] = message.sender
        running_conversations = MessagingService().get_active_conversations(user, active_recipient)
        kwargs['running_conversations'] = running_conversations
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Checks for valid form and submit with updating message object.
        :param form: form object
        :return: Redirect to cuurent message conversation.
        """
        obj = self.get_object()

        if self.request.user == obj.sender:
            recipient = obj.recipient
        else:
            recipient = obj.sender

        message = form.save(commit=False)
        message.sender = self.request.user
        message.recipient = recipient

        message.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'The message is sent with success!')
        return redirect('direct_messages:user_message', obj.pk)


@method_decorator([login_required], name='dispatch')
class MessageView(RedirectView):

    permanent = False
    query_string = True
    pattern_name = 'direct_messages:user_message'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
         Prepares redirect url when the project owner accept the proposal.
        """
        user = self.request.user
        chatroom = ChatRoom.objects.filter(Q(sender=user) | Q(recipient=user)).first()
        if chatroom:
            return super().get_redirect_url(*args, pk=chatroom.pk)
        messages.warning(self.request, 'You do not have any messages to show.')
        return reverse('direct_messages:list_message')
```

**direct_messages.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% load humanize %}

{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/message.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/profile.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<section id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="messaging">
        <div class="inbox_msg">
            <div class="inbox_people">
                <div class="headind_srch">
                    <div class="recent_heading">
                        <h4>Recent</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="inbox_chat">
                        {% for chat in conversations %}
                            <div class="chat_list {% if forloop.counter == 1 %} active_chat {% endif %} ">
                                <a style="display: block;
                                   height: 100%;
                                   width: 100%;
                                   text-decoration: none;"
                                   href="{% url 'direct_messages:user_message' chat.pk %}" class="fill-div">
                                    <div class="chat_people" >
                                        <div class="chat_img" >
                                            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ chat.recipient.profile_photo.url }}" alt="sunil">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="chat_ib" >
                                            <h5>{{ chat.recipient }}</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="mesgs">
                    <div class="msg_history">
                        {% for conversation in running_conversations %}
                            {% if user == conversation.sender %}
                                <div class="outgoing_msg">
                                    <div class="sent_msg">
                                        <p>{{ conversation.content | safe }}</p>
                                        {% if conversation.document %}
                                        <a type="button" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#A9A9A9; border: 3pt lightgrey" class="badge badge-secondary" target="_blank" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ conversation.document.url | safe }}" >See attachment</a>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <span class="time_date">{{ conversation.sent_at | naturaltime }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                <div class="incoming_msg">
                                    <div class="incoming_msg_img">
                                        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ conversation.sender.profile_photo.url }}" alt="{{ conversation.recipient.username }}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="received_msg">
                                        <div class="received_withd_msg">
                                            <p>{{ conversation.content | safe }}</p>
                                            {% if conversation.document %}
                                            <a type="button" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#A9A9A9; border: 3pt lightgrey" class="badge badge-secondary" target="_blank" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ conversation.document.url | safe }}" >See attachment</a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <span class="time_date">{{ conversation.sent_at | naturaltime }}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="type_msg">
                        <div class="input_msg_write">
                            <form method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {% for field in form %}
                                    {{ field }}
{#                                    {% if field.help_text %}#}
{#                                        {{ field.help_text }}#}
{#                                    {% endif %}#}
{#                                    {% for error in field.errors %}#}
{#                                        {{ error }}#}
{#                                    {% endfor %}#}
                                {% endfor %}
                                <button class="msg_send_btn" type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" style="font-size:15px" aria-hidden="true"> </i> </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Update your question with the output you are getting

Comment: what do you want organize exactly messages in individual chat or list of chats according to time? and if you want to organize list of chats then you have to update last chat update time of every conversation when new message arrives or send to the chat and arrange according to the last update time

Comment: @Bhupeshlad Sorry, I did not clearly explain what I want. I need to organize the list by most recent.

Comment: @KurtJonson does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to organize chats then you should update your model like:

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    """
    A private char room

    Attributes:
        created_at (datetime): datetime value when chatroom is created.
        recipient (user): user whom the chatroom sends first message.
        sender (user): user who created the chatroom
    """
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='chatroom_sender', verbose_name='Sender'
    )
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='chatroom_recipient'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('sent at', auto_now_add=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField('last message',auto_now=False)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ('sender', 'recipient')
```

then you have to update `last_update` field when new message arrives from sender or send by user and arrange chat list according to `last_update` time like:

```
chats = ChatRoom.objects.all().order_by('-last_update')
```

I hope this is what you want

This is the code to start a new conversation, I am developing a freelance marketplace so a new conversation will only be made when the employer accepts the proposal of the freelancer

```
class ProposalAcceptView(RedirectView):
    """
    Aceept a proposal.
    """
    permanent = False
    query_string = True
    pattern_name = 'jobs:job_detail'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        job = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        job.freelancer = User.objects.get(username=kwargs.get('username'))
        job.status = 'working'
        job.save()

        # Create message opening
        is_chatroom = False
        try:
            chatroom = ChatRoom.objects.get(sender=self.request.user, recipient=job.freelancer)
            is_chatroom = True
        except:
            pass

        if not is_chatroom:
            try:
                chatroom = ChatRoom.objects.get(sender=job.freelancer, recipient=self.request.user)
            except:
                pass

        if not is_chatroom:
            chatroom = ChatRoom.objects.create(sender=self.request.user, recipient=job.freelancer)

        print('is chatroom', is_chatroom)
        print('chat roo', chatroom)

        print('chat room created....')

        MessagingService().send_message(
            sender=self.request.user,
            recipient=job.freelancer,
            message="""
            Hi {username},

            Your proposal is accepted.

            Project details: <a href='{url}'>{job}</a>
            """.format(username=job.freelancer.username,
                       url=reverse("jobs:job_detail", kwargs={"pk": job.pk}),
                       job=job.job_title
                       )
        )

        messages.success(
            self.request, 'User : {} is assiged to your project'.format(kwargs.get('username'))
        )

        return super().get_redirect_url(*args, pk=kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: Hi! I tried what you said and it does not work. In my inbox list, the very first message is still the newly created conversation. I might try to edit my services.py to see if the problem is in those lines of code.

Comment: can you share the code in which you add new conversations?

Comment: now in here you have to set last_update = time.now() while calling chatroom each time if it not exit then create with last_update and if  exits then update last_update time to current time